# SPO Document UniqueID return value is null

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I'm using [SharePointPnP](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell) Module 
I'm trying to extract some property information from each document located under one list
One of the issues that I'm currently facing at the moment is the property **$Item.UniqueID** on row 29
it's throwing an exception because the return value of the UniqueID is $null 
However, when I step into my script and run the following command in Powershell Console **$Item** I get the list of properties for the keys and its values including the UniqueID !!!

My question is, why am I getting a $null value while I'm iterating in each item?

Here is my powershell script:

```
try
{
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url 'https://SomeCompany.sharepoint.com/FOA/BD/' -Credentials O365

    $Items = Get-PnPListItem -List 'Budget' | Where-Object{$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq 'File'}
    $ItemsFieldValues = $Items.FieldValues | Where-Object {$_.FileDirRef -like '*Models' -and $_.Title -like '*.xlsx' -and $_.Title -like '*-*'}
    $dtItems = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    $dtItems.Columns.Add("ID", "Int64") | Out-Null
    $dtItems.Columns.Add("OperatingUnit","String") | Out-Null
    $dtItems.Columns.Add("HotelName","String") | Out-Null
    $dtItems.Columns.Add("Title", "String") | Out-Null
    $dtItems.Columns.Add("FileLeafRef", "String") | Out-Null
    $dtItems.Columns.Add("FileDirRef", "String") | Out-Null
    $dtItems.Columns.Add("UniqueID", "Guid") | Out-Null
    $dtItems.Columns.Add("ModifiedBy", "String") | Out-Null
    $dtItems.Columns.Add("ModifiedOn", "String") | Out-Null
    $dtItems.PrimaryKey =$dtItems.Columns[0]

    ForEach($Item in $ItemsFieldValues)
    {
        $TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format s
        $NewRow = $dtItems.NewRow()
        $NewRow.ID = $Item.ID
        $NewRow.OperatingUnit = $Item.Title.Split('-')[0]
        $NewRow.HotelName = ($Item.Title.Split('-')[1]).Split('.')[0]
        $NewRow.Title = $Item.Title
        $NewRow.FileLeafRef = $Item.FileLeafRef
        $NewRow.FileDirRef = $Item.FileDirRef
        $NewRow.UniqueID = $Item.UniqueID #$Item.UniqueID return value is $null
        $NewRow.ModifiedBy = $Global:CurrentUserName
        $NewRow.ModifiedOn = $TimeStamp
        $dtItems.Rows.Add($NewRow)
    }

    if($dtItems.Rows.Count -gt 0)
    {
        $SQLConnection.Open()
        $BulkCopy = New-Object("Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy") $SQLConnection
        $BulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[Models].[HotelsModels]"
        $BulkCopy.WriteToServer($dtItems)
    }
}

catch
{
    $ErrorLog = "Error On " + (Get-Date) + ";$($_.Exception.Message) - Line Number: $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)"
    Write-Error "$($_.Exception.Message) - Line Number: $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)"
    $NewRow = $Global:dtErrorLog.NewRow()
    $NewRow.TimeStamp = [System.datetime]::Now
    $NewRow.ErrorLog = $ErrorLog
    $Global:dtErrorLog.Rows.Add($NewRow)
    Save-ErrorLog
}
Finally
{
    $SQLConnection.close()
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the **UniqueID** must be a case sensitive
Here is the correct script

```
 $NewRow.UniqueID = $Item.UniqueId
```

Thanks